# How to know whether I have LAMP or XAMPP installed in my Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, lamp

I am currently working in PHP in my localhost. I have php version 5.5.9-1, apache2 version 2.4.7, and Mysql Ver 14.14 in my Ubuntu 14.04.
But how to check whether I am using LAMP or XAMPP?

I tried typing "lamp" and "xampp" in terminal. But it shows "command not found".  Should I come to the conclusion that these things(apache, mysql and php) were installed seperately?

Comment: @SuneelKumar — https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-xampp-stack-on-ubuntu-15-04/

Comment: @SuneelKumar  https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html also shows linux downloads...

Comment: Why does it matter how the software was installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to understand this :

**1) LAMP**

For LAMP setup, you have to install PHP, Apache and Mysql packages separately. In LAMP you don't get anything to manage your server in GUI way.
**For Ex**: To start apache server you have to type command in terminal.
To start apache : `sudo service apache2 start`

For installing LAMP refer :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

**2) XAMPP**

It is a complete package which comes bundled with PHP,Apache, Mysql etc in a single installation. It gives you a control panel from which you can manage your server and configuration files.It is something of this sort.

[image]

For XAMPP : https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

**If you don't find xampp control panel in your system, this means you have a LAMP setup. i.e : first option.**

Answer (score 11):

In my case I have installed XAMPP for Linux (LAMPP) in Ubuntu 18.10

How can you know it?

1. Try to go to **/opt/lampp**
2. If you can, it means Xampp for Linux it's installed, but if you want to know the version, in the same path of step 1, put in your command line **./xampp status**
   You will know XAMPP for Linux version and Apache, MySQL and ProFTPD status (running or not).

**Know PHP version**

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./php -v
```

**Know MySQL (MariaDB) version**

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./mysql --version
```

**Know Apache version**

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./apachectl -v
```

I hope helps somebody

[./xampp status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhCwL.png)

Answer (score 1):

The lamp package installs apache, mysql and php separately.

In ubuntu you should have the apache installed on `/etc/apache2`

the mysql installed on `/etc/mysql`

and the php installed on `/usr/share/php`

If you are developing you can use PHP's [built-in server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Comment: I have apache, mysql, and php installed in my system. Does it imply that I have LAMP?

Comment: Yes, it does! You have LAMP installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

xampp -v

If xampp is installed it will display the version else its not installed.

Comment: Good. It means xampp is not installed :)

Comment: @informer I'm sure that I've install XAMPP on my Ubuntu Server (my webpage is working) but when i try this command, it shows "command not found" too.